# Converting between CRS in degrees to meters in Qgis 2.10.1

Tags: qgis-2

I am trying to get the area of my region in in square meters. 
I am actually on WGS 84 EPSG:4326 and when I switch the CRS, 
I can only find WGS 84/UTM which returns the same answer. Is my answer correct? What am I missing out?

Comment: How exactly are you trying to switch the CRS?? If you are in  WGS 84 then you have degrees and not meters.

Comment: I am having difficulties switching to UTM so that I can read my distance in meters directly. I simply do not know the right UTM to use. I am in the equatorial region (11,3)

Comment: If you can tell us what area your data is in, we might be able to help. UTM is in vertical bands, so we need the west-most and east-most longitudes.

Answer (score 1):

I am still not sure what you want for prj. This is a simple example to save a file in prj you want. I have a file in EPSG:4326 and I want it in 2100 (in meters).
[image]

From my layer i choose Save as and then I pick the CRS I want
[image]
[image]

But you have to understand the importance of a CRS and decide the one you want to have.

Comment: as I earlier stated, I am working in Cameroon and my works maps all fall within the geo-coords lon/lat:11 / 3. I really have no idea which UTM will be best for me, that is my obstacle